# In C, using pointers, why is it possible to overwrite an array element inside a function and why can we return the address of this array element?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I know that if we call a function using "call by value" we cant overwrite the value we are passing to the function inside the function, and if the function returns a pointer value, we must not try to return the address of a local variable (local to the function) because this local variable gets distroyed after the function is executed (and this results in a warning), but look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *fun(int x,int y, int c[]){
    c[0]=100;
    x=887;
    return &c[0];
}

int main()
{
    int x=10,y=20,*z;
    int c[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    z=fun(x,y,c);
    printf("%d\n",*z);
    printf("%d\n",c[0]);
    printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
```

The output is :

100
100
10

So, we are not changing the value of "x" (main function x) but we are actually changing the value of c[0] (main function c[0]), and for what i know this should not be possible because im using call by value and not by reference, can you explain this to me please?

And also, if i change the line of code "return &c[0];" for this line of code "return &x;" i dont get a warning in the first statement but i get a warning in the second, why does this happens?

Comment: *"why can we return the address of this array element?"* Because the array isn't local to the function: it was passed by the caller.

Comment: *"I'm using call by value and not by reference."* An array is never passed to a function (except when it is a `struct` member). The array decays to a pointer to its first element, and that pointer is passed to the function. So `int *fun(int x,int y, int c[])` is identical to `int *fun(int x,int y, int *c)`

Comment: The `return &x;` is doing what you previously said you know you must not do: return the address of a local variable. But `return &c[0];` is OK because although the pointer is local to the function, what it points to is not.

Answer (score 2):

As a pointer is referencing an object you can change that object by dereferencing the pointer. It does not matter where this object is (of course if the object exists - which is a problem when you return a pointer to the automatic storage duration).

> im using call by value and not by reference, can you explain this to
> me please?

No, you pass reference to the first element to the array `c` defined in `main`. ***Arrays are not passed by value!!!***

To avoid confusion change the function declaration to:

```
int *fun(int x,int y, int *c)
```

> And also, if i change the line of code "return &c[0];" for this line
> of code "return &x;" i dont get a warning in the first statement but i
> get a warning in the second, why does this happens?

because you return reference to the first element of array `c` defined in function `main` which is **not** local to the function `fun`